# Use of "rather" instead of "whether"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to correct what I see as a frequent mis-speak from a friend of mine, but I first want to make sure that I am not the one in error.

> I'd like to know whether the following use is correct, or rather if it is incorrect.

The above sentence uses both the words "whether" and "rather" as I expect them to be used, but  this friend says things like "Rather you like it or not..." or "Rather you're black, white or Asian..."

I wonder if this is just a regional usage, or is it incorrect as I suspect?

Comment: To my knowledge, it seems that your friend is using the term incorrectly. This usage is not in accordance with any regional usage that I've heard.  I think your suspicions that the person has misheard the term are well-founded.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I'll discreetly show him the error of his ways. Thank you.

Comment: Your sentence 'I'd like to know whether the following use is correct, or rather if it is incorrect.' is on the surface tautological, but has the pragmatic sense 'I'd like to know whether the following use is correct – or rather,  I'm hoping that someone will confirm that it is incorrect.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Whether' shows alternatives for example 'Whether it rains or not, we will go on a trip.' whereas 'Rather' shows preference for eg. 'I'd rather do this instead of that'. So the sentences you mentioned here should use 'whether' rather than 'rather'. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather shouldn't be used at the beginning of a sentence that way, but can be used this way:

> I'd rather not do that.

Comment: There are plenty of sentences that begin with *Rather*.  Just not this kind. :)

Comment: @tchrist is correct. There are already questions and answers about using it at the beginning of a sentence. I'm asking about what I found to be a rather odd use where the context demands a different connotation than I am accustomed to. I suspect that this person has just mis-heard this his whole life, but I wanted to make sure I'm not mistaken before I say something. _And, I thought it would make an interesting Q&A._